# I'm trying to setup a ROR with postgres project, but facing these issue, how to resolve them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm trying to set up DB, so I used this command: rake db:create.
It resulted in this error, I don't know how to debug this as am new to ROR.

Error:

```
The `rake` executable in the `redis-rack` gem is being loaded, but it's also present in other gems (rake).
If you meant to run the executable for another gem, make sure you use a project specific binstub (`bundle binstub <gem_name>`).
If you plan to use multiple conflicting executables, generate binstubs for them and disambiguate their names.
The `rake` executable in the `rake` gem is being loaded, but it's also present in other gems (redis-rack).
If you meant to run the executable for another gem, make sure you use a project specific binstub (`bundle binstub <gem_name>`).
If you plan to use multiple conflicting executables, generate binstubs for them and disambiguate their names.
W, [2021-10-19T15:11:57.605014 #21509]  WARN -- Skylight: [SKYLIGHT] [4.1.2] Running Skylight in development mode. No data will be reported until you deploy your app.
(To disable this message for all local apps, run `skylight disable_dev_warning`.)
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Comment: which os are you using? did you install Postgres and run the server?

Comment: Os- Windows. I have installed Postgres and the pgAdmin server is running

Comment: is this running ruby on windows or via wsl?

Comment: It's running vis wsl

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `rake` instead of `rails` as the command? What versions of ruby and rails (and, indeed, postgres) are you using? But the error says that it can't connect to postgres - are you sure the server is actually running and accepting connections at the defined location? (If you're on Windows, the fact it's looking for a Unix location may be a hint.) How have you defined your database config in your app?

Answer (score 0):

you could try a fresh installation of PostgreSQL like so:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get remove postgresql

sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

then

```
sudo service postgresql status
```

to make sure its online